Removing all popups from mapboxgl map
I'm adding popups to a mapbox map using:
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({closeOnClick: true, offset: [20, 0]})

But how do I remove all popups, for example, with an event listener?
I've tried this but it says popup is undefined:
document.getElementById('mySelect').onchange = function(){
  popup.remove()
}

And, tried this, but it just prints an empty element:
document.getElementById('mySelect').onchange = function(){

const element = document.getElementsByClassName("mapboxgl-popup");
    console.log("element is", element)
    for (el in element) {
      console.log(el)
    }
}

So what is the best way to remove ALL popups from an existing mapboxgl map?

To remove all the popups from a Mapbox map, I would use one of these two solutions :
DOM Manipulation
This case require a for...of loop, for example :
function removeAllPopups() {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("mapboxgl-popup");
    const elementsArray = Array.from(elements);
  elementsArray.forEach(function(el) {
      el.remove();
  });
}   

This is closer to your example, and works as the for...in loop in your sample.
Storing instances
This is likely the solution I would choose, where pop-ups are stored in an array :
var activePopups = [];

function addPopup() {
    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ closeOnClick: true, offset: [20, 0] })
    activePopups.push(popup);
}

function removeAllPopups() {
    activePopups.forEach(function(popup) {
        popup.remove();
    });
    activePopups = [];
}

Here's a full example :


mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibHVsdWNteSIsImEiOiJjbHg0cGs3bjUxN2d2MnFxeGhmam1vam95In0.GcBY5JWMkCOvov6bcvol_A';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v12',
    center: [-62.83293, 17.89589],
    zoom: 13
});

var activePopups = [];

function getRandomCoordinate(lng, lat, maxOffset = 0.01) {
    var randomLng = lng + (Math.random() - 0.5) * maxOffset;
    var randomLat = lat + (Math.random() - 0.5) * maxOffset;
    return [randomLng, randomLat];
}

function addPopup() {
    var baseLngLat = activePopups.length === 0 ? map.getCenter().toArray() : activePopups[activePopups.length - 1].getLngLat().toArray();

    var randomLngLat = getRandomCoordinate(baseLngLat[0], baseLngLat[1]);

    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
            closeOnClick: true,
            offset: [20, 0]
        })
        .setLngLat(randomLngLat)
        .setHTML('<h1>Nice popup</h1>')
        .addTo(map);

    activePopups.push(popup);
}

function removeAllPopups() {
    activePopups.forEach(function(popup) {
        popup.remove();
    });
    activePopups = [];
}

document.getElementById('addPopupBtn').onclick = function() {
    addPopup();
};

document.getElementById('removePopupsBtn').onclick = function() {
    removeAllPopups();
};
 body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 #map {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
}
 #controls {
     position: absolute;
     top: 10px;
     left: 10px;
     z-index: 1;
     background: white;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 5px;
}
 button {
     margin: 5px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mapbox Remove All Popups</title>
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.10.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.10.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="controls">
      <button id="addPopupBtn">Add Popup</button>
      <button id="removePopupsBtn">Remove All Popups</button>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>



